# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package not for tests package

Tags: python

I know this has been asked many times but somehow I am not able to get over this error. Here is my directory structure-

```
project/
  pkg/
  __init__.py
  subpackage1/
        script1.py
        __init__.py
  subpackage2/
        script2.py
       __init__.py
```

script2.py has:

```
class myclass:
    def myfunction:
```

script1.py has

```
 from ..subpackage2 import script2
```

I also tried

```
from ..subpackage2 import myclass
```

And this gives me : ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This answer explains what's going on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73149/769971

You're probably running script1.py from inside the subpackage1/ directory. 
Change your import to be `from subpackage2 import script2`, back up to the pkg/ directory, then run `python -m subpackage1.script1`.

Comment: this works for me. I think my error was trying to run python script with `python ./subpackage1/script1.py` instead of `python -m subpackage1.script1`, it is totally wrong!!!