# Python - ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: python-2.7

This is my directory structure.

```
PyCharm
    Python
        PRD
            _AppFunc
                DbUtils.py
                __init__.py

            _AppCode
                DataExtract.py
                __init__.py

            __init__.py

        __init__.py
```

And my PYTHONPATH is set to C:\Users\username\Desktop\PyCharm\Python\PRD

In DataExtract.py I am trying to import DbUtils.py using

```
from .._AppFunc import DbUtils
```

And getting this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\PyCharm\Python\PRD\_AppCode\DataExtract.py", line 36, in <module> from .._AppFunc import DbUtils   
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

If I move DBUtils.py out of _AppFunc folder and under PRD, it works fine. 
But I intend to keep it in a separate folder to restrict access.

I have read most [stack overflow threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193670/valueerror-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-not-for-tests-package) related to this and [python doc on intra-package-references](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) but couldn't get it to run.

How do I go about it !?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked...

1. The `PYTHONPATH` should be set to the root. For the directory structure in question it is `C:\Users\username\Desktop\PyCharm`
2. Each folder and sub-folder in the structure starting from root should be made a package. Copy paste `__init__.py` and `__init__.pyc`
3. The module is imported in the main file by a full path reference. For this question it is `Python.PRD._AppFunc import DbUtils`