# How to import module into a python unit test

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this has been asked a lot of times, been looking at it for the last two hours and still can't figure it out. Would be very grateful for a solution to my actual problem rather than a link to someone else problem if possible.

Here goes...

```
/src
    /moduleA
        __init__.py
        messages.py
    /tests
        testA.py
```

**messages.py**

```
def get_messages(paramA):
    if paramA:
        return "A"
    else:
        return "B"
```

**testA.py**

```
import unittest
from moduleA import messages
```

My unit test will simply check whether `A` or `B` is returned from the `get_messages(...)` function.

As I understand it, `moduleA` is a module as it has an `__init__.py` file. VSCode does not complain about the `from moduleA import messages` line in my test however when I try to execute `testA.py` I get the following error message...

`ImportError: No module named moduleA`.

Also tried running it with `python -m`

Would be very grateful if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I can change my file structure around if that would help. Perhaps the examples I've been reading are for Python 3 and I'm using 2.7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my suggestion on how to take care of this: [ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package not for tests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193670/valueerror-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-not-for-tests-package/37193862#37193862)

So you'll need to add a `__init__.py` to your `test` directory, back up one directory to  `src` then run `python -m test.testA` and you should be good to go.

Also, once you see that to run successfully, you'll see that you have a syntax error in `get_messages`: you're missing a colon after `else`.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, we should check configuration before running the file.

Cross check with spaces like:

```
ENVIRONMENT=mock
PYTHONPATH=./src
```